# How to compute function rolling averages maximum for each possible interval length?

Tags: algorithms

I'm searching for a fast way to calculate

$$ g(k):=\max_{0<i<T-k} {\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=i}^{i+k} f(j)}$$

for $ 0<k \le T $ given some discrete function $f$ defined on $ [0; T]$.

Is there algorithm to do it faster then naive $O(n^2)$? If so, how?

Comment: Actually, your title contradicts to question text, so what you mean - max over all k faster than O(n^2) or max for given k?

Comment: Formula in question text is correct. I need max of rolling average for all possible k. in other words I need to calculate T values: each of those values is max value od rolling average of given length.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to compute rolling function is to keep/recompute old data and on each step "add" new data and subtract the data going out of the window. So, you need to transform your sum function into updateSum one:

sum(i+1) = updateSum(sum(i), f(i), f(i+k+1))

Comment: This will give me $O(n^2)$ if Im calculating for each possible k.